# Pass Attr Value from PHP MYSQL to jQuery iFrame

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have tried to pass a value from the id attribute in my php script $row['coupon_id'] to the jquery but every time when the link is clicked the alert box will keep popping out the same id e.g in my case the '147' for all the link that being clicked instead of showing out different id which are pulled from my database.

Could anyone lend me a hand on this?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleDivs() {
        var deal_id = $('.buttonClicked').attr('id');
        alert(deal_id);     
}

    $('.buttonClicked').click(function(){
        toggleDivs();
    }); 
});     
</script>

<?php
    include('include/class_dbcon.php');
    $connect = new doConnect();
    $query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM coupons "
                       . "WHERE coupon_status = 1 "
                       . " ORDER BY coupon_id DESC LIMIT 12";

    $result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data);
    $msg = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $msg .= "<span class='buttonClicked' id='"
            . $row['coupon_id']
            . "'><a href='#'>Detail</a></span></br>";
      } 

echo $msg;

?>

<div id='iframecall'></div>
```

Thanks
Fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler's wrong, change it to:

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var deal_id = this.id;
    alert(deal_id);     
}

$('.buttonClicked').click(toggleDivs);
```

Your original code didn't consider which element was clicked.  The call to `$('.buttonClicked').attr('id')` got a set of all the links, and returned the id of the first one in the set.

Comment: Thanks @searlea that is a great 1. Btw could I check with you if it is possible to integrate the live() into the function? e.g. $('.buttonClicked').live('click',function(){       toggleDivs();
}); as currently all mysql event will be posted using the ajax to be processed there in a different pages. So the event failed to be triggered if it is on separate pages. Any idea on that? Thx

Comment: Sure..., but you should *avoid* pointlessly wrapping things in `function() { ... }` if you don't need to.  If you keep wrapping like that, you lose the magic of `this` in the callback function.

Comment: Hi @searlea, I tried to include the the toggleDivs in the live function `$('.buttonClicked').live('click',function(){ toggleDivs(); });` and as per the input u provided I ended up with `undefined` error when the link was clicked. Seem that the `this` failed to be addressed. Anyway how can I address this issue? Is there other way to get the value besides using the function `this.id` to get the value? Thanks Fire

Comment: **Don't** wrap things in `function() { ... }`.  I might as well be explicit I guess: `$('.buttonClicked').live('click',toggleDivs);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @searlea. You save me days of researching on this issue. MILLION THX:)